# Cannot edit ConstraintLayout in Layout Editor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to edit a ConstraintLayout in the layout manager in Android Studio 3.0. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
>
> Exception Details java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ConstraintLayout_Layout
>     at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:440)
>     at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.(ConstraintLayout.java:420)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)

I can't actually drag around items, they all seem to be tiny dots in the upper left corner, although the layout works fine on the emulator.

I tried to follow advice from different questions on here. I rebuilt the project, invalidated cache, made sure that the ConstraintLayout support repositories are installed and in the gradle script (`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`), changing the theme in editor, but nothing helped.

What else could I try to fix the problem?

Edit: my build.gradle (Module:app) file: https://gist.github.com/meyerlasse/44f06e18d6dab50593325f25f9b62bd2

Comment: Double check that you have the correct dependencies in your Gradle file.

Comment: It's very possibly a bug in the recent versions of AS 3.0. It was working fine in AS 3.0 Canary 3 I think, then it went downhill.

Comment: I'm seeing this exact issue in Android Studio 2.3.3..